# How can I calculate difference between dates in days/months and bucketing them in respective years?

Tags: python, r, excel

I would like to calculate the difference between dates for example "08-Oct-2015 and 30-Mar-2017" and bucket them into years like

2015  x days

2016  y days

2017  z days

Is there any R library or How can I write a function to do that.

Please let me know thanks in advance.

Comment: as.Date() might be a good place for you to start looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you an overall different in days and at the same time defines a vector of Date endpoints:

```
diff( y <- as.Date(c("08-Oct-2015","30-Mar-2017"), format="%d-%b-%Y") )
Time difference of 539 days
```

This lets you use seq and table to generate a tabulation that does your counting:

```
table( format( seq( y[1], y[2], by=1), "%Y") )

2015 2016 2017 
  85  366   89
```

If you assign the value returned from table it can be indexed either by position or by name:

```
 daytbl <- table( format( seq( y[1], y[2], by=1), "%Y") )
 daytbl["2015"]   # should return 85 with "2015" as a "name"
```

Answer (score 1):

The lubridate package has a lot of ways to read in different date formats and calculate appropriately.  The examples you gave you could use

```
dmy('08-Oct-2015')-dmy('30-Mar-2017')
```

You could group by year from there.

Comment: If you want to bin by year, this approach won't really work, as it returns a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a Python module that could do exactly this in one line but a few lines should do:

from datetime import datetime

```
def bucket_year_days(start_date, end_date):
    ''' Assumes start_date and end_date are already parsed to datetime '''
    years_dict = {}
    tmp_date = start_date
    while tmp_date <= end_date:
        next_date = datetime(tmp_date.year+1, 1, 1)
        years_dict[tmp_date.year] = (next_date - tmp_date).days
        tmp_date = next_date

    return years_dict
```